# absolute div width 90% - xpx

Tags: css, margin, css-position

I have 2 absolute divs.

```
left: 10%;
position: absolute;
width: x px;
z-index: 1;
margin-left: -540px;
```

and

```
left: 10%;
z-index: 0;
width: <some big number>px;
position: absolute;
margin-left: -199px;
```

Div A is over div B and is the logo of the site.

Div B is under div A and works as a infinite background (some big number big).

With that solution I can scroll horizontaly along the some big number sized background.

I need something like that:

```
left: 10%;
z-index: 0;
width: 90% + 199px;
position: absolute;
margin-left: -199px;
```

Does anyone have a solution for this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `calc()` if you are ok with using CSS3.

Something like:

```
width: calc(90% + 199px)
```

Check [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/calc) for browser support and the need for vendor prefixes.